# Is a recursively defined sequence also a first-order difference equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am currently trying to understand the paper [Simple mathematical models with very complicated dynamics](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/237005499_Simple_Mathematical_Models_With_Very_Complicated_Dynamics) by Robert M. May. Here, the term "First-order difference equations" is used in another way than how I learned it, which makes me question the meaning of "First-order difference equation"

I learned that first-order difference equations are equations which involve the first derivation like this (let $f,g,y:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$):

$\frac{dy}{dx} = f(x)*g(y)$

But in the paper it is claimed that an equation, which essentially is a recursively defined sequence, is also a "first-order difference equation", like the following equation which also appears in the paper:

$X_{t+1} = aX_t(1-X_t)$

Is there some kind of more general definition for a "first-order difference equation" which I am missing? Because there clearly isn't a derivation of any kind in the last equation.

Comment: For difference equation you don't need derivative. When you have $u_{n+1}$ then it's a first order difference equation. And first order differential equation are not the same as difference equation. Maybe you are confusing both ?

Comment: You are right, I was confusing them both, thank you

Comment: yw Rakagami........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = f(x)*g(y)$$
This is a first order **differential** equation. It as you mentioned involves derivatives. It's also separable.
$$u_{n+1}+5u_n=15$$
Is a first order linear **difference** equation. it dosen't involves derivatives. You are surely confusing both kind of equations.

Comment: Similar to differential equations, [difference equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Relationship_to_difference_equations_narrowly_defined) can be more specifically defined by finite differences. In your example, this would be $$\Delta u_n+6u_n=15$$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I was reading that article on Wikipédia yesterday because some authors make no difference between recurrence relationship and difference equations.

Comment: Yes, as it points out, you can interchange them simply be writing out the differences or condensing them into differences, so the distinction is moot. It does give motivation to the naming though.

Comment: Yes you're right @SimplyBeautifulArt I was just a bit confuse about naming though.. Some books use difference equations where other books use another naming. Recurrence relationship.

Answer (score 0):

What you have in mind is first order *differential* equations. Difference equations are discrete analogue of differential equations where instead of derivatives, the equation involves the difference between the value of a sequence at later step and the previous step ($X_{t+1}$ and $X_t$)